# if (validBeverage == true) were to be replced with (validBeverage) does it change the logic of the code? if yes why or whynot?

Tags: c++

Replace the line
if (validBeverage == true)
with the line
if (validBeverage)
and run the program again. Are there any differences in the execution of
the program? Why or why not?

im home learning C++, and my friend who goes to college keeps giving me his assignments to practice, could someone explain to me how this works, cause im getting the same results, i just want to know why?

```
    // #include <iostream>
    // #include <iomanip>
    // using namespace std;

    // int main()
    // {
        // int number; //number of beverages
        // float cost; //cost of beverage
        // int beverage; //beverage type    
        // bool validBeverage;

        // cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

        // do
        // {
            // cout << endl << endl;
            // cout << "Hot Beverage Menu" << endl << endl;
            // cout << "1: Coffee         $1.00" << endl;
            // cout << "2: Tea            $ .75" << endl;
            // cout << "3: Hot Chocolate  $1.25" << endl;
            // cout << "4: Cappuccino     $2.50" << endl << endl << endl;

            // cout << "Enter the beverage 1,2,3, or 4 you desire" << endl;
            // cout << "Enter 5 to exit the program" << endl << endl;
            // cin >> beverage;

            // switch (beverage)
            // {
            // case 1: validBeverage = true;
                // break;
            // case 2: validBeverage = true;
                // break;
            // case 3: validBeverage = true;
                // break;
            // case 4: validBeverage = true;
                // break;
            // default:validBeverage = false;
            // }

            // if (validBeverage == true)
            // {
                // cout << "How many cups would you like?" << endl;
                // cin >> number;
            // }


            // switch (beverage)
            // {
            // case 1: cost = number * 1.0;
                // cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                // break;
            // case 2: cost = number * .75;
                // cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                // break;
            // case 3: cost = number * 1.25;
                // cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                // break;
            // case 4: cost = number * 2.50;
                // cout << "The total cost is $ " << cost << endl;
                // break;
            // case 5: cout << "Thank you.  Please come again." << endl;
                // break;
            // default:cout << "You entered an invalid selection.\n";
                // cout << "Try again please" << endl;
            // }

        // } while (beverage != 5);

        // return 0;
    // }
```

Comment: I hope your "friend" is not handing in your solutions as if they were his own. That would be a very serious violation of academic code, general ethics and friendship.

Comment: Please _read_ the tags you use: this is not a BASIC program.

Answer (score 5):

It will make no difference to the meaning of this code because every line is commented out.

Comment: I hate you for spotting this first:(

Answer (score 2):

Because `validBeverage` is a `bool`, these two are precisely equivalent:

```
if (validBeverage == true)

if (validBeverage)
```

It is a matter of personal style as to which you choose to use.

Comment: Thanks, I don't share my work with him, he just gives me his assignments.  and sorry about the basic tag..he told me it's he's learning c++ basics so i just figured. Thanks for clarifying that anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

The only change to the logic of the code is:

Answer (score 0):

The if(condition) is satisfied when condition is true. 0,false and NULL are considered non-true values. All others values are considered true.

This is how your code executes,

```
if( validBeverage == true)
```

becomes

```
if( true/false)
```

Return value of == operator is true or false. Therefore validBeverage == true returns either true or false
The if clause is now checked.
Therefore the check has two stages.

To better understand,try this

```
int condition = (validBeverage == true)
if(condition) { ... }
```

In the following code,

```
if(validBeverage)
```

The check is one stage.

Comment: The first paragraph is pretty misleading. It ignores the concept of types and pretends that the expression `NULL` is something that it's not. The rest is good.

Comment: i tried to simplify it for him @LightnessRacesinOrbit.

Comment: more of a thumb rule than c++ standard.

Comment: In this case you "simplified it" by removing facts and adding myths :)